# Google Places autocomplete, any way to restrict the location and categories?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder, google-places-api

Is there any way to filter the Google Places Autocomplete for a specific location and also filter based on categories (like restaurants, malls etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Google Places Autocomplete has [type](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html#place_types) and [location](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html#location_biasing) parameters.

Comment: The "type" parameter only accepts "geocode" or "establishment" parameters. From the page". Currently, two types are supported:
geocode instructs the Place service to return only geocoding (address) results. Generally, you use this request to disambiguate results where the location specified may be indeterminate.
establishment instructs the Place service to return only business results"

Comment: the thing has changed, some time ago there have been types like restaurant, etc...

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, it looks like the AutoComplete API only accepts "establishment" for all non-address places and "geocode" for geographic entities. You might be able to write some JS that makes an additional Google Places API call for each possibility and returns a new array of full Google Places API details.